# How to select columns based on date in one column and NaN in second column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame like below:

[image]

And I would like to select only these rows where col1 >= 2015-01-01 and col1 is NaN, how can I do that?

I tierd to use: `df[(df["col1"] >= "2015-01-01") & (df["col1"].isna())]` and it does not work.

Comment: `col1 >= 2015-01-01 and col1 is NaN` How do you expect both the conditions to be `True` at any instance of time.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question title, probably you want this:

```
df[(df["col1"] >= "2015-01-01") & (df["col2"].isna())]
```

I presume you want to check `NaN` on `col2` instead of `col1`.

Result:

```
         col1 col2
0  2015-01-02  NaN
```